# Accounting format displays $0.00 sometimes and $ - others

Tags: excel, pivot-table, number-formatting, rounding-error, excel-2002

I have a pivot table in Excel and the sum of the items should equal zero.  Instead I am getting a number very, very close to zero (-3.63797880709171E-12).  As @Tim Williams pointed out in his comment this is a known artifact of decimal <--> binary floating point conversions.

My main concern here is really in the formatting of the result.  I am trying to apply an accounting format where a $0 shows as `$ -` as opposed to `$0.00`.  The `$ -` format is important because it allows you to look at a glance and see which columns "tie out" when comparing sets of numbers.  When some zeroes display as `$0.00` and others display as `$ -` this is much more difficult.

For example,

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════╦══════════╗
║                   Formula                    ║  Result  ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════╬══════════╣
║ = 1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1  ║  $ 0.00  ║
║ =-1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1  ║  $(0.00) ║
║                                           0  ║  $   -   ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════╩══════════╝
```

I would like the result for all three formulas to show as `$  -`.  Is there a way to force that to happen?  Perhaps there is a way to force sums in a pivot table to round to the nearest penny (i.e., hundredth)?

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/rounding.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your formula to this so that it rounds to the nearest 10th (change the last 1 to something bigger if you need more precision).

```
= round(1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1, 1)
```

Edit:
If you are unable to change the formula, you can also use a custom display format For the result along the lines of:

```
[<0.05]"-";[>-0.05]"-";$0.00
```

I have not tested this, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Those three formulas I showed were just to illustrate one half of the problem.  The other part of the problem is that this is specifically an issue for me in a **pivot table**.  If you know of a way to round the sum in a pivot table, that would likely solve my problem.

Comment: Can you round the results before they are fed into the pivot table?

Comment: Your "Edit" did it for me.  I had to adjust it a bit to get it to work, but I was finally able to do that.  Here's the final number format I used:  `[>=.005]_($* #,##0.00_);[<=-.005]_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)`